# Commercetools - Use query predicates to filter on a collection attribute

Tags: predicate, commercetools, sphere.io

I'd like to get all the Category items that have between their ancestors an ancestor with a certain "id".

Here is the JSON of one of the categories returned by **GET**ting from `/categories`:

```
{
        "id": "4627f3b0-fe52-4cc6-b03e-3fd72e701342",
        "version": 1,
        "lastMessageSequenceNumber": 1,
        "createdAt": "2019-02-18T13:48:51.677Z",
        "lastModifiedAt": "2019-02-18T13:48:51.677Z",
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "clientId": "_anonymous"
        },
        "createdBy": {
            "clientId": "_anonymous"
        },
        "key": "snowboard-gloves",
        "name": {
            "en": "Snowboard Gloves"
        },
        "slug": {
            "en": "snowboard-gloves"
        },
        "description": {
            "en": "Gloves specifically designed for snowboarding"
        },
        "ancestors": [
            {
                "typeId": "category",
                "id": "b27086d2-33f2-43c3-aad1-4c01b2b9a886"
            }
        ],
        "parent": {
            "typeId": "category",
            "id": "b27086d2-33f2-43c3-aad1-4c01b2b9a886"
        },
        "orderHint": "0.000016",
        "metaTitle": {
            "en": "Snowboard Gloves"
        },
        "metaDescription": {
            "en": "Gloves specifically designed for snowboarding"
        },
        "assets": []
    }
```

I'd like to call the `/categories` API with a *where* clause on `ancestors[x].id = "b27086d2-33f2-43c3-aad1-4c01b2b9a886"` but from the [documentation](https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-query-predicates) I don't understand how I should write the query predicate.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query predicate follows the structure of the json response. Nested fields are accessed with `()` brackets.

Try this out

```
ancestors(id = "idb27086d2-33f2-43c3-aad1-4c01b2b9a886")
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. But I ended up filtering on parent.id since I was looking for direct descendants only!

(I wasn't able to understand the syntax of the query predicates because Postman wasn't sending the "where" parameter in the correct format)